# Cannot install ghostscript, libgs9 and libpaper1 on Debian Bullseye

Tags: linux, debian, installation, docker, apt

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install \
    --no-install-recommends -qq -y \
    apt-utils \
    poppler-utils \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    pdftk \
    ghostscript \
    autoconf-archive \
    pkg-config \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    imagemagick \
    wget \
    procps \
    curl \
    locales \
    libicu-dev \
    libpango1.0-dev \
    g++ \
    make \
    tesseract-ocr \
    tesseract-ocr-por \
    tesseract-ocr-osd
```

I can build it through `sudo docker build -t foo .` on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker version 19.03.10), but I can't do the same on Travis CI:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpaper1:amd64
 libgs9:amd64
 ghostscript
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install     --no-install-recommends -qq -y     apt-utils     poppler-utils     libjpeg-dev     libcairo2-dev     pdftk     ghostscript     autoconf-archive     pkg-config     libpng-dev     libtiff5-dev     zlib1g-dev     imagemagick     wget     procps     curl     locales     libicu-dev     libpango1.0-dev     g++     make     tesseract-ocr     tesseract-ocr-por     tesseract-ocr-osd     libc6     libgs9     ucf     libpaper1' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Part of log regarding libpaper1:

```
Setting up libpaper1:amd64 (1.1.28+b1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Creating config file /etc/papersize with new version
stat: cannot statx '/etc/papersize.dpkg-inst': Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package libpaper1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpaper1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Part of log regarding libgs9:

```
dpkg: error processing package libgs9:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Part of log regarding ghostscript:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript:
 ghostscript depends on libgs9 (= 9.53.3~dfsg-7+deb11u1); however:
  Package libgs9:amd64 is not configured yet.
```

I tried the following without success:

```
RUN dpkg --configure -a && apt-get -f install
```

and also:

```
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install --fix-broken

RUN apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends -qq \
```

Part of my `.travis.yaml`:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: Build temporary docker image
      services:
        - docker
      language: minimal
      if: type = pull_request AND branch = master
      script:
        - source ci_scripts/gcloud_setup.sh
        - gcloud docker -- pull gcr.io/foo/bar
        - docker build --cache-from gcr.io/foo/bar:latest -t bar_temp .
        - docker tag bar_temp gcr.io/foo/bar
        - gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/foo/bar
```

Am I missing something here? How can I install those packages without error?